# Background Image for header

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to add background image to the header and set the background position for it. Here`s my code which is not working..

HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Home</title>
<!-- Meta viewport tag is to adjust to all Mobile screen Resolutions-->
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Jstyle.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="project">


        <div data-role="header" class="header"></div>

        <div id="ad" align="center">

            <img alt="image" src="images/ad.png">

        </div>


        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="product" align="center">
                <img alt="image2" src="images/product.png">

            </div>




            <!-- Style card  -->

            <div id="style" align="center">
                <img alt="image2" src="images/style_card.png">

            </div>
            <!-- Social  -->

            <div id="social" align="center">
                <img alt="image2" src="images/app_store.png"> <img
                    alt="image2" src="images/social.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
.header{

background-image:url("images/image_bg_inner.png");

width:200px;

background-color: #B00C0C;
```

}

Tried with `.ui-header` also.. and it`s not working. Please help me how can I do the same..

Comment: what is not working? it is not displaying image?

Comment: Your header is empty? So maybe no height?

Comment: @axel.michel right! he should use `min-height` property ;) or if his header height will be of fixed value then `height`

Comment: Yes Yes my header is empty..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try :**

```
.header {
width:200px;
background-image:url("images/image_bg_inner.png");
}
```

Maybe the `background-color` is conflicting with `background-image`.

**Or:**

Add height to your header.

```
.header {
width:200px;
background-color: #B00C0C;
background-image:url("images/image_bg_inner.png");
min-height:70px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-header {
  height:200px; /* any height */
  background-image:url(newlogo.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.ui-bar-a{
    background-image:url("images/image_bg_inner.png");
    width:200px;
    background-color: #B00C0C;
}
```

If you are using another theme change to .ui-bar-b etc. Width 200px seems odd on that element though?